# Is it possible to write comments for @helpers in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-declarative-helpers

Suppose I have a helper like this defined in my `App_Code\Helpers.cshtml`:

```
@helper PageHeader(string h1, string h2) { 
    <h1>@h1</h1>
    <h2>@h2</h2>
}
```

I would like to know how can I add xml comment to it that describes what this helper does, as well as describes the parameters, i.e. as you would normally do it in .NET code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Description
/// </summary>
```

... so that I get that comment picked up by VS intellisense.